# Form validation using commons validator framework

Tags: validation

I have ten fields in my form and at least one field should be filled by user. How can we achieve this by using commons validator framework.

Comment: I tried to create my own validator in validator-rule.xml and created method for that in a class.can u help how to proceed or how to solve this problem?

Comment: I thought to do it like required but when i make field required then form will not get submit until all field are filled.how to customize it or any other solution for this?